# How to proxypass a folder /abc to domain on different port

Tags: apache, jboss, vhosts

Not sure how to define it correctly but the problem is...

I have a situation where i need to proxypass a directory (/abc) on apache 'vhost_ssl.conf'  i.e

`/abc  https://1.1.1.1:4443/abc`    (1st jboss server running in host)

`/abc  https://1.1.1.1:2308/abc`    (port 2308 is mapped to VM IP:4443, second jboss server running in Vmware)

now i am trying to proxypass the URL:-

`https://mysite.com/server1/abc`  -> which proxy to `https://1.1.1.1:4443/abc`

`https://mysite.com/server2/abc` -> which proxy to `https://1.1.1.1:2308/abc`

here, i am hoping the dummy folder server1 and server2 will separate the request. any suggestion, or perhaps a work through will be grateful for me.

thanks.

Comment: I tried a wordaround which nearly worked. i.e

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to use mod_rewrite module in apache.

Please refer the below link for **mod_rewrite**

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Rewrite rule will be kind of below lines.

```
<VirtualHost Host_Address:443>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/server1/abc$ https://1.1.1.1:4443/abc
    RewriteRule ^/server2/abc$ https://1.1.1.1:2308/abc

    -----------
    -----------
</VirtualHost>
```

This can be added in **httpd-vhosts.conf** file
Hope this will helpfull to you.

Comment: thanks for suggestion, I tried put that in my vhost_ssl.conf and the url redirected to "https://1.1.1.1:4443/abc" but browser throwed error: Error 118 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT): The operation timed out. The URL https://1.1.1.1:4443/abc does work in my host browser. i would like to say here that my actual configuration differs where apache connectes to ajp connector to talk with jboss.. i.e  ProxyPass /abc ajp:1.1.1.1:8009/abc. For more info i have this pastbin : http://pastebin.com/vCThanDB